# How to upload file from a custom module?

Tags: 8, media, files

I am trying to create one basic module for Drupal 8, where I have added one form with some textfields and multiple file upload element.
Now on "submitForm" I am saving textfields values on database, but I am not sure how I can save image fields. I will be only saving the filename in the database.

Will it be using same function as we have in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you upload a file, it stores the file temporarily in **file_managed** table in database.And you have to set the file permanent status 1 to save it permanently else it will be deleted from the table by cron after some time.
This sample code to load a image and save it to database might help you to understand.

```
/* Fetch the array of the image file stored temporarily in database */
$image = $form_state->getValue ('image');

/* Load the object of the image file by it's fid */
$file = File::load ($image[0]);

/* Set the status flag permanent of the image file object */
$file->setPermanent();

/* Save the file in database ( "managed_file" table) */
$file->save();
```

when you select any file from **'managed_file'** field type, drupal make a entry in **'file_managed'** table, you just have to set the permanent flag as above to decide whether you have to save it permanently or not.

Comment: @parth.k  , you may accept the answer if it worked for you so other people see easily the answer is right.